# How to disable focus on pressing Tab rather than one input field using javascript

Tags: javascript, tabs, focus

The basic problem is I have one text field and some buttons on screen. 
I dont want my text field to loose focus on any keypress/or mouse click.
Its working fine for mouse but when I press TAB it switches focus to URL and then buttons. I want to disable tab use or it should move out focus from that input field at any cost.

Comment: Please can you show us your current code attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For disabling the field switching by pressing `tab` key:

```js
$('input').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 9) {
    $(this).focus();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="field1">
  <input type="text" id="field2">
  <input type="text" id="field3">
  <input type="text" id="field4">
  <input type="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

I've updated MH2K9's answer so that it doesn't need jQuery.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('keydown', handleKey, true);

function handleKey(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Tab') {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```